# Oblivion's objects and textures are messed up after installation of some mods using Vortex Mod Manager

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I just installed some mods to *TES IV: Oblivion* via Vortex Mod Manager, and when I load my last save (of non-modded *Oblivion* — it was actually in Shivering Isles, which textures one of the mods upscaled), it is messed up. Objects and textures show up as exclamation marks inside a yellow diamond, as the image below shows:

[image: screenshot of scenario described above]

My mod list is:

- Facial Textures by Enayla
- 4GB RAM patcher
- Shivering Isles Upscaled Textures (SIUT)- kart_SIUT_default_2x (I tried to disable this mod but it still persisted)
- Disabled Vegetation (I tried to disable this mod but it still persisted)
- Dark UI Vdot40

I am using the latest OBSE.

Where could the problem be?

Comment: The exclamation-marks-inside-a-diamond models appear when a model can't be found. The same seems to have happened to your textures. Vortex is currently not a recommended mod manager for everyone, as stated on their page. How did you install and uninstall the mods? Does Vortex install straight into the Data folder, or use its own folder?

Comment: I have never had luck getting Vortex, or the previous Nexus Mod Manager, to work with Oblivion. You may be best off backing up your saves, uninstalling all mods and the game, reinstalling the game, and installing your mods with OBMM.

Comment: Make sure Vortex uses hardlink deployment, this makes it easier to uninstall graphic mods. Personally I think Vortex is a much needed improvement to Nexus Mod Manager and have no issues using it. Had 100+ mods on Oblivion 8 months ago, currently running Skyrim SE with 500+ mods.
Make sure to use LOOT as well to properly order your mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. It was caused because almost all plugins related to certain DLC **was Disabled by default in Vortex Mod Manager** so I did have to **Enable** them.

Comment: You know what, it Vortex did that for me with Fallout 3 recently, though in that case the game just refused to start at all... nice find!

Comment: @nightsurfer Thanks :) I am glad it helped you too :)